# Hosting MSFT WebView2 browser control in a QT QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, webview2

I am hosting the WebView2 browser control on a QWidget within a C++ QT 6 application, but the control is not visible.

My steps for initializing and navigating are:

1. Create a subclass of QWidget to host the control
2. Create the environment via CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions
3. Create the controller via CreateCoreWebView2Controller, passing the HWND returned by QWidget::winId()
4. Set the bounds of the parent and control
5. Navigate to a url via IWebViewCore::Navigate

I've verified the NavigationStarted, NavigationCompleted, TitleChanged, and DOMContentLoaded events are called as expected.

Spy++ shows a window called "Chrome_WidgetWin_0" (with several child windows) as a child of the QWidget.

But it's not visible.

Any ideas what's missing or wrong, or how to troubleshoot? Has anyone gotten QT and WebView2 to work?

Comment: The two things I would forget to do and end up with the same symptoms you describe (not with QT but getting WebView2 hooked up to other UI frameworks) is not setting the Bounds or not setting the Bounds correctly ( [0,0] should be the upper left of the HWND you give to WebView2. Usually the bounds rect is [0,0, width,height] ) and forgetting to set the CoreWebView2Controller IsVisible property to true.